# Maven creates an empty pom.xml file in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

Create Maven project. `File` -> `New Project` -> `Maven`. Archetype do not indicate.

Then everything is standard: `GroupId` and `ArtifactId`. The project is created with empty `pom.xml`

[image]

I am trying to create a new Maven project. I am getting an empty pom.xml file. I did not install java and maven. I used the OpenJDK Java version 17 and maven from the IDE itself.

Comment: For a temporary solution, you copy my `pom.xml` to yours. https://github.com/donhuvy/sample_jaxb_java7/blob/main/pom.xml . The behavior of IDE was strange.

Comment: May you check idea.log for errors after reproducing? Do you notice something like `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: named capturing group is missing trailing '}'
`

Comment: no exception just tried to create a new project. All it shows is pom.xml(unknown).

Comment: also it doesnt create src,main and test folders in the project directory. When i clicked maven window it shows maven(Unknown). How do i resolve this issue?

Comment: You need to select an archetype, otherwise it won't know what to put in the pom.xml

Comment: You can try using spring intializr there you can add dependency in pom.xml as per your requirement and you can download that maven project, after that open that project in intellij you will get a pom.xml with all your dependencies.

Comment: i'll try that thanks  to all of you

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek IntelliJ does not require you to select an archetype and should generate a default POM without one specified.

Comment: You could try reinstalling IntelliJ.

Answer (score 8):

I was having the same problem. I was using JDK 20 in my IntelliJ, I switched to JDK 17 and changed in new project creation section too and the problem was solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I did the same and worked for me, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Check your environment variables and see if JAVA_HOME is present and if your downloaded JDK bin is added to system path variable. If not add them.

Variables should look sth like this:

JAVA_HOME:  C:\Users\username\ .jdks\openjdk-18.0.1.1

path:  C:\Users\username\ .jdks\openjdk-18.0.1.1\bin

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem. Install jdk8 and resetting it,You probably installed jdk18.

jdk8 download url
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#java8-windows

Comment: JDK 8 is very out of date and insecure. I'd recommend using a higher version if possible.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: jdk17 works fine but 18 and 19 are having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled the version I had and installed the last version, it worked for me, of course I deleted the cache and saved configurations with the options the uninstaller gives to erase configuration data. I did a clean installation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).